# Windows 7 boot error - nothing boots up

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, usb-flash-drive, bsod

When I came to my computer it was with a BSOD. After I rebooted, Windows started showing that error message where you have to put the installation CD to fix it/boot. 
"Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause."
Then it asks to start Startup Recovery, I say go, and the it comes with the same error message, asking to put windows CD, choose language, etc... and a error code:
0xc0000225

Problem is after I did that, the progress bar loading files just goes to a screen with the background and mouse cursor. And stay there forever.

OK, now this is where it gets weird. When I use my USB pen-drives that I've always used to fix those kind of problems (WinPE) the same happens. It goes to the progress bar loading files and then to the cursor and black background, stays there. Then I made the Hirens boot CD and when I choose miniXP THE SAME HAPPENS, background and mouse cursor, nothing else.

I've never seen this situation and I don't know what to do, because I can't use stuff like Windows CD or partition magic to see what's wrong with the boot.

Comment: Do you recall the error message(s)?

Comment: Not right now, but I will go to that computer and check it out exactly for you.

Comment: Ok, I've edit the OP.

Comment: [See if this works](https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc0000225/)

Comment: I believe it's an HD physical failure problem.

Comment: If that's the suspected issue, then you can try connecting it as an external device to another PC or use a live disc of any Linux distro (Ubuntu, fedora, mint etc) and backup your data as much as possible before any more attempt to fix.

Comment: Forgot to add how to check for errors via Ubuntu: http:// www.howtogeek.com/howto/37659/the-beginners-guide-to-linux-disk-utilities/   http:// www.upubuntu.com/2012/12/check-for-bad-sectors-on.html?m=1 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1496679